# I want to get the type of a variable at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection

I want to get the type of a variable at runtime.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

So, strictly speaking, the "type of a variable" is always present, and can be passed around as a type parameter. For example:

```
val x = 5
def f[T](v: T) = v
f(x) // T is Int, the type of x
```

But depending on *what you want to **do***, that won't help you. For instance, may want not to know what is the type of the variable, but to know if the type of the *value* is some specific type, such as this:

```
val x: Any = 5
def f[T](v: T) = v match {
  case _: Int    => "Int"
  case _: String => "String"
  case _         => "Unknown"
}
f(x)
```

Here it doesn't matter what is the type of the variable, `Any`. What matters, what is checked is the type of `5`, the value. In fact, `T` is useless -- you might as well have written it `def f(v: Any)` instead. Also, this uses either `ClassTag` or a value's `Class`, which are explained below, and cannot check the type parameters of a type: you can check whether something is a `List[_]` (`List` of something), but not whether it is, for example, a `List[Int]` or `List[String]`.

Another possibility is that you want to *reify* the type of the variable. That is, you want to convert the type into a value, so you can store it, pass it around, etc. This involves reflection, and you'll be using either `ClassTag` or a `TypeTag`. For example:

```
val x: Any = 5
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def f[T](v: T)(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = ev.toString
f(x) // returns the string "Any"
```

A `ClassTag` will also let you use type parameters you received on `match`. This won't work:

```
def f[A, B](a: A, b: B) = a match {
  case _: B => "A is a B"
  case _ => "A is not a B"
}
```

But this will:

```
val x = 'c'
val y = 5
val z: Any = 5
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def f[A, B: ClassTag](a: A, b: B) = a match {
  case _: B => "A is a B"
  case _ => "A is not a B"
}
f(x, y) // A (Char) is not a B (Int)
f(x, z) // A (Char) is a B (Any)
```

Here I'm using the *context bounds* syntax, `B : ClassTag`, which works just like the implicit parameter in the previous `ClassTag` example, but uses an anonymous variable.

One can also get a `ClassTag` from a value's `Class`, like this:

```
val x: Any = 5
val y = 5
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def f(a: Any, b: Any) = {
  val B = ClassTag(b.getClass)
  ClassTag(a.getClass) match {
    case B => "a is the same class as b"
    case _ => "a is not the same class as b"
  }
}
f(x, y) == f(y, x) // true, a is the same class as b
```

A `ClassTag` is limited in that it only covers the base class, but not its type parameters. That is, the `ClassTag` for `List[Int]` and `List[String]` is the same, `List`. If you need type parameters, then you must use a `TypeTag` instead. A `TypeTag` however, cannot be obtained from a value, nor can it be used on a pattern match, due to JVM's *erasure*.

Examples with `TypeTag` can get quite complex -- not even comparing two type tags is not exactly simple, as can be seen below:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
def f[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit evA: TypeTag[A], evB: TypeTag[B]) = evA == evB
type X = Int
val x: X = 5
val y = 5
f(x, y) // false, X is not the same type as Int
```

Of course, there are ways to make that comparison return true, but it would require a few book chapters to really cover `TypeTag`, so I'll stop here.

Finally, maybe you don't care about the type of the variable at all. Maybe you just want to know what is the class of a value, in which case the answer is rather simple:

```
val x = 5
x.getClass // int -- technically, an Int cannot be a class, but Scala fakes it
```

It would be better, however, to be more specific about what you want to accomplish, so that the answer can be more to the point.

Comment: The example code you wrote after "But this will:" is confusing. It compiles but the result is not the one you show in the comments. Both calls return the same result: "A is a B". Because the value `5` is both an instance of `Int` and an instance of `Any`.
Apart from that, your explanation was perfect :)

Comment: @Readren The value isn't tested for, the class is. `Int` is `Any`, but `Any` is not `Int`. It works on Scala 2.10, and it _should_ work on Scala 2.11, and I don't know why it isn't.

Comment: It scares me to contradict an eminence like you, but the code `a match { case _: B => ...` test the type of the actual value of the variable `a`, not the type of the variable `a`.
You are right in that it returns what you say in scala 2.10.6. But it should be a bug.
In scala 2.11.8 the type of the actual value is tested, as it should.

Comment: Very nice coverage on differences between ClassTag and TypeTag, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to null check this?

Answer (score 57):

I think the question is incomplete. if you meant that you wish to get the type information of some typeclass then below:

If you wish to print as you have specified then:

```
scala>  def manOf[T: Manifest](t: T): Manifest[T] = manifest[T]
manOf: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T])Manifest[T]

scala> val x = List(1,2,3)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> println(manOf(x))
scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
```

If you are in repl mode then

```
scala> :type List(1,2,3)
List[Int]
```

Or if you just wish to know what the class type then as @monkjack explains `"string".getClass` might solve the purpose

Comment: for readers: this is the **most useful solution**. As in Javascript `typeof x`, here `manOf(x)` say the data type!

Answer (score 26):

If by *the type of a variable* you mean the runtime class of the object that the variable points to, then you can get this through the class reference that all objects have.

```
val name = "sam";
name: java.lang.String = sam
name.getClass
res0: java.lang.Class[_] = class java.lang.String
```

If you however mean the type that the variable was declared as, then you cannot get that. Eg, if you say

```
val name: Object = "sam"
```

then you will still get a `String` back from the above code.

Comment: You can also do `name.getClass.getSimpleName` for a more readable output

Answer (score 23):

i have tested that and it worked

```
val x = 9
def printType[T](x:T) :Unit = {println(x.getClass.toString())}
```

Comment: It doesn't tell the sub types of class. As mentioned above, for both List[String] and List[int]  , it will return same thing: List

Answer (score 7):

```
instance.getClass
```

above method return path of instance's Class.
to get the exact Class name of the instance, try this:

```
instance.getClass.getSimpleName
```

here is the example:
[image]