# How to check if a variable is a list in scala: Any is list?

Tags: scala

How to check if a variable is a list in scala: Any is list?

I need something like

```
def isList(variable: Any): Boolean = {
  // code here for returning true or false
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19388888/3248346

Comment: I saw this, but I cant say just "List" in this case. Compiler said List takes params. Looks like List[_] or List[Any] will work here as suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `isInstanceOf` method

```
 def isList(variable: Any): Boolean =  variable.isInstanceOf[List[_]]
                                                  //> isList: (variable: Any)Boolean
  isList(List(1,2))                               //> res0: Boolean = true
  isList(1)                                       //> res1: Boolean = false
  isList(Array(1,2))                              //> res2: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 5):

```
scala> def isList(v: Any) : Boolean = v match {
           case _: List[_] => true
           case _ => false
       }
isList: (v: Any)Boolean

scala> isList(List(1))
res0: Boolean = true

scala> isList(Array(1))
res1: Boolean = false
```