# Scala Compiler Plugin: How to access the specific type information of an override method in subclass?

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

I'm developing a Scala Compiler Plugin, trying to transform every function call like

```
myfuncall(1)
```

into

```
val newvalue = myfuncall(1)
newvalue
```

However, I get into trouble due when the function call is the return value of another function. Here's the code that I want to transform

```
class A[C]
class B[C] extends A[C]

trait MyTrait[C] {
    def func1: A[C]
}

object MyObject extends MyTrait[Int] {
    def func1 = new B
}
```

In the sample above, compiler can successfully infer that the result of `new B` should be converted to `A[Int]`, because the `func1` in `MyObject` should have the same return type as `func1` in `MyTrait[Int]`.

However, problem arises when I do the transformation with my compiler plugin.

```
class A[C]
class B[C] extends A[C]

trait MyTrait[C] {
    def func1: A[C]
}

object MyObject extends MyTrait[Int] {
    def func1 = { 
        val newvalue = new B
        newvalue
    }
}
```

Now, the `newvalue` doesn't provide any extra type information, instead the compiler has to infer it. The result type of `newvalue` is `B[Nothing]`, which is the most specific type the compiler can infer.

Then problem occurs when I try to pass `newvalue` as the return value of `func1`. `func1` requires `A[Int]`, while `newvalue` is of type `B[Nothing]`, which can not be matched.

The problem can be solved if I can know the required return type of `func1` in advanced, since I can specify `newvalue` with this return type, as following shows

```
class A[C]
class B[C] extends A[C]

trait MyTrait[C] {
    def func1: A[C]
}

object MyObject extends MyTrait[Int] {
    def func1 = { 
        val newvalue: A[Int] = new B
        newvalue
    }
}
```

The code above can be compiled successfully.

My question is, how can I know the return type of `func1` in `MyObject` is `A[Int]` when writing a Scala compiler plugin, since the signature of `func1` doesn't tell its return type.

I think finding out how compiler gets `A[Int]` as the return type of `func1` in `MyObject` from the signature of `func1` in `MyTrait[Int]` can also be helpful.

When `MyTrait` and `MyObject` are defined in two different source files, this problem becomes more difficult.

Comment: Heres a way to get function return type programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414651/how-to-get-scala-functions-parameters-return-type