# Mixed types in Scala List

Tags: scala

I'm newer to Scala, for `List`, it seems like only one type of value are allowed, but following code run ok:

```
thrill = "Will" :: "fill" :: "until" :: 3 :: Nil
println(thrill)
List(Will, fill, until, 3)
```

even this:

```
val thrill = "Will" :: "fill" :: "until" :: (1,2,3,4, (1,2,3)) :: Nil
println(thrill)
List(Will, fill, until, (1,2,3,4,(1,2,3)))
```

How Scala infer this type of List from its elements? How to print the type of the List?

Comment: To print the type of the List you can do `type thrill` in the REPL which will return `Any` for the first one and `java.io.Serializable` in the second.

Comment: @Brian means `:type`.  That is a REPL command so you need the colon.

Comment: Scala infers the type by finding their highest common supertype denominator. There is a bit more to it, but that's the way you can think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the type of an object at runtime and you are not in the REPL you can do it with a simple function like this:

```
def manOf[T: Manifest](t: T): Manifest[T] = manifest[T]
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19388313/302793). Having this function defined you can call

```
println(manOf(thrill))
```

to print the information you are looking for.

The reason why your code works is that a list can have a very general type like `List[AnyRef]` or `List[Any]`. The latter allows you to store anything in the list. The scala compiler is quite smart about type inference and it will pick the most specific type parameter possible given your arguments.

If you append a new element to an immutable list (immutable is the default), you will get a new list that may have a new (more general) type.

**Example**

```
val l = List(1)
```

will give you a `List[Int]`. Adding a double element like this

```
val l2 = 1.0 :: l
```

gives you a new list with type `List[AnyVal]`. In general the compiler picks the most specific type that is a supertype of all values in the list.