# How to obtain class type from case class value

Tags: scala

I have the following code snippet:

```
case class Test(i:Int)

val b = Test // b: Test.type
val a = Test(1) // a: Test
```

Is there a way to get from value `a` which has a `Test` type to `Test.type`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to get the type of a variable at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386964/i-want-to-get-the-type-of-a-variable-at-runtime)

Comment: `Test.type` is the type of the **companion object** of the `Test` _class_, it is not the type of the class of `a`. Why exactly do you want this? Can you share your use case?

Answer (score 2):

Add `libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value` to `build.sbt` and then you can try

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{Type, TypeTag, typeOf}

case class Test(i:Int)

val b = Test
val a = Test(1)

def getType[A: TypeTag](a: A): Type = typeOf[A]

getType(a) // Test
getType(a).companion // Test.type

getType(b) // Test.type
getType(b).companion // Test
```